Why can't include-days in CalendarPicker be a dynamic value in WhatsApp Flows?
I'm building a WhatsApp Flow and using a CalendarPicker component. I need to dynamically restrict the selectable days (e.g., weekdays only). However, when I define include-days as a dynamic value in the data section, it doesn't work.
Here's the JSON I tried:
"include_days": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "__example__": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
}

And referenced it in the CalendarPicker as:
"include-days": "${data.include_days}"

This throws an error, and the component doesn't render properly. Static values like ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"] work fine, but I need this to be dynamic. Is there a limitation with include-days in WhatsApp Flows, or is there a different way to make it dynamic?
Here is the doc from whatsapp official https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/reference/components#calendarpicker
here is the doc from whatsapp official
Complete example here:

{
  "routing_model": {
    "calendar_screen": []
  },
  "data_api_version": "3.0",
  "version": "6.2",
  "screens": [
    {
      "id": "calendar_screen",
      "title": "Seleccionar Fecha",
      "terminal": true,
      "data": {
        "min_date": {
          "type": "string",
          "__example__": "2024-12-01"
        },
        "max_date": {
          "type": "string",
          "__example__": "2025-12-31"
        },
        "unavailable_dates": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "__example__": ["2024-12-25", "2025-01-01"]
        },
          "include_days":  {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "__example__": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
        }
      
      },
      "layout": {
        "type": "SingleColumnLayout",
        "children": [
          {
            "type": "CalendarPicker",
            "name": "appointment_date",
            "label": "Selecciona una fecha",
            "helper-text": "Selecciona una fecha disponible.",
            "required": true,
            "mode": "single",
            "min-date": "${data.min_date}",
            "max-date": "${data.max_date}",
            "unavailable-dates": "${data.unavailable_dates}",
             "include-days": "${data.include_days}",
            "on-select-action": {
              "name": "data_exchange",
              "payload": {
                "appointment_date": "${form.appointment_date}"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "Footer",
            "label": "Finalizar",
            "on-click-action": {
              "name": "complete",
              "payload": {}
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}


